# how to use MatrixForm on a matrix after applying NumberForm on it?

Tags: matrix, output-formatting, display

V 12.1 on windows.

I do not remember if I've seen this and googling is not helping.

I wanted to format a numerical matrix for display using `MatrixForm`. But first I wanted to apply `NumberForm` on each entry, because I wanted all entries to have same width when displayed (so they do not shift around during display and running.

But `NumberForm` does not work well with `MatrixForm`. Is there a way around this?

```
a = {{1.3432, 34.432123}, {5.65454, 78.9883}}
MatrixForm[a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
a = {{1.3432, 34.432123}, {5.65454, 78.9883}};
b = NumberForm[a, {2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it is the above I want to display in `MatrixForm` But it does not work on it due to the `NumberForm` wrapper in between

```
 MatrixForm[b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also doing things in reverse ofcourse does not work either

```
 NumberForm@MatrixForm[a]
```

I could ofcourse use `Round` on the matrix first, then apply `MatrixForm` but I prefer to use things like `NumberForm` and `AccountingForm` since they allow more control on the format.

Is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: This is a little less convenient that xzczd's solution, so I'm just leaving this as a comment: `Map[NumberForm[#, {2, 2}] &, {{1.3432, 34.432123}, {5.65454, 78.9883}}, {2}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: `(a // MatrixForm) /. x_?NumberQ :> NumberForm[x, {2, 2}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Export` suffers similar problem. The solution I found is, use `*Form` only on numbers:

```
a = {{1.3432, 34.432123}, {5.65454, 78.9883}};
Clear[numberForm]
numberForm[a_List, n_] := numberForm[#, n] & /@ a
numberForm[a_, n_] := NumberForm[a, n]
b = numberForm[a, {2, 2}]
MatrixForm@b
```

[image]